# Swift 2: Checking a value

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am looking for a method to check a value that is slowly increasing if it has increased by 500. Each time it has increased by 500 i would like to run some actions.

Comment: Although I think @totiG has deciphered what you're after you should really review [ask] to know what makes a good question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to check if the value has increased by 500. The % checks the remainder, so if it is 0 you know it has increased by 500:

```
let value = 1500
if value % 500 == 0 {
    print ("true")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague. Also try posting some code on stack overflow.

Did you try running a method in the update function?

Like

```
if myValue == 500 {
 // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your value a property and use the didSet function, which gets called each time the value of the property is changed.

If you need to monitor a property from another class then yo could make the class who's property is being monitored a subclass of NSObject and use KVO. Personally, I find KVO to be syntactically ugly a pain to set up, but your milage may vary.